# count number of unique combinations pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have trouble creating a summary statistic for my data.
My dataframe looks like this

```
id   status
a    approved
a    approved
b    draft
b    redraft
c    redraft
c    draft
d    approved
d    draft
```

desired outcome:

```
status_combo       id_count
approved,approved  1
draft,redraft      2
approved,draft     1
```

The code I'm using

```py
df1=df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(tuple).rename('status_combo')
df2=df1.groupby(df1).size().reset_index(name='id_count')
print(df2)
```

create all combination of status where the order of status is included too however for me the desired outcome should treat draft,redraft and redraft,draft as one type of status_combo
Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sort` the column before making it into `tuple`

```py
df1 = df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).rename('status_combo')
df2 = df1.groupby(df1).size().reset_index(name='id_count')
```

```
print(df2)

           status_combo  id_count
0  (approved, approved)         1
1     (approved, draft)         1
2      (draft, redraft)         2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
df = df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg(
    status_approved=('status',lambda x:','.join(sorted(tuple(x))))).groupby(
    'status_approved', as_index=False).agg(id_count=('id', 'count'))
```

print(df):

```
     status_approved  id_count
0  approved,approved         1
1     approved,draft         1
2      draft,redraft         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with a simple oneliner:

```
df.groupby('id').agg(set).reset_index().status.value_counts()
```

Result:

```
{redraft, draft}     2
{approved}           1
{draft, approved}    1
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

Or in your solution add `sort_values('status')`:

```
df1=df.sort_values('status').groupby('id')['status'].apply(tuple).rename('status_combo')
df2=df1.groupby(df1).size().reset_index(name='id_count')
print(df2)
```

Result:

```
           status_combo  id_count
0  (approved, approved)         1
1     (approved, draft)         1
2      (draft, redraft)         2
```